# Unable to use launched kdb+tick demo

Tags: batch-file, cmd, kdb

I'm following the following kdb+tick demo: [DEMO](http://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/startingq/tick/)

There does not seem to be any error when I launch `run.bat` but all the `q` instances in the different `cmd` windows seem to be stuck.

Namely, the `q)` command does not show up, so after the process has displayed  the `q.q` message, the cursor is blinking on an empty line. Therefore, I am unable to execute any queries.

The only window that *does* show something is `ticker.bat` which shows (after `q.q` message):

```
k){ON!x y}
'<
@
"q"
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://ww..
q))
```

Why can't I use the other processes? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error in ticker.bat is the process attempting to execute an html file as code. Check what arguments are in ticker.bat then check that source file. I think you'll find you've download html instead of the raw text version.